# Error pushing docker image to dockerhub using gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, docker, spring-boot

I am trying this [Spring boot with docket example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#scratch) using Gradle, but getting the following error on running the task `gradle build buildDocker`

```
C:\Users\zeeshan\Workspace\MyWorkspace\SpringBootDocker>gradle build buildDocker
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build
:buildDocker FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildDocker'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.092 secs
```

The Docketfile exists in src\main\docker in my windows machine.

My **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "${nexusUrl}/content/groups/public" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    }
}

group = 'mydockergroup'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'docker'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "${nexusUrl}/content/groups/public" }
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  push = true
  applicationName = jar.baseName
  dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from jar
      into stageDir
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** I copied my workspace in a Ubuntu system and it worked fine. Is there a problem setting the file path for dockerfile in my build.gradle for Windows system?

Answer (score 0):

We are specifying dockerDirectory in docker-maven-plugin. I think you may required to setup similar in gradle.

```
<dockerDirectory>${basedir}/docker</dockerDirectory>
```